# Is "word" in my examples countable or not?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/word%2Frumor%20has%20it):
>
> **(1)** *Word has it that the neighbors are moving next month*.

> My variants:
>
> **(2)** *Word on the street has it that the neighbors are moving next month*.
>
> **(3)** *The word is that the neighbors are moving next month*.
>
> **(4)** *The word on the street is that the neighbors are moving next month*.

Is "*word*" in (1)-(4) countable or uncountable and why?

Thanks!

Comment: It's clearly uncountable. There aren't multiple words on the street.

Comment: It's vague, but it's definite. It means "rumor" or "gossip" and is just as countable as those words -- i.e, maybe and maybe not, depending on context. What difference does it make, anyway? What depends on their countability?

Comment: John Lawler, I'm just curious how to determine whether "word" is countable or uncountable here.